# Does missing maxOccurs signify unbounded

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am creating a SOAP web services using Axis2 and in the response I am returning a complex type. When Axis2 generated the wsdl, it assigns 1 to minOccurs however the maxOccurs is no where to be found. Does this mean that the missing maxOccurs is unbounded or is it some default value like 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) in w3cshool, it's 1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So where and what should I change if I want Axis2 to generate wsdl with maxOccurs as unbounded ?

Answer (score 1):

> The default value for both the minOccurs and the maxOccurs attributes is **1**

from

[XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/)